# Unique values across ManyToMany fields on Django

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, constraints, unique

I need some assistance with a quite simple problem (simple to explain, but not to solve for me)

I have the following model in Django:

```
class ClassGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(_('group'), max_length=3)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,
                               related_name='classgroups',
                               related_query_name='classgroup',
                               verbose_name=_('course'))
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Actor,
                                      related_name='student_classgroups',
                                      related_query_name='student_classgroup',
                                      verbose_name=_('student'))
    lecturers = models.ManyToManyField(Actor,
                                       related_name='lecturer_classgroups',
                                       related_query_name='lecturer_classgroup',
                                       verbose_name=_('lecturer'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('class group')
        verbose_name_plural = _('class groups')
        unique_together = ('group', 'course')
```

I need to add a constraint that prevents an Actor to be a student and a lecturer at the same time in each ClassGroup. Is it possible to add such a constraint at the model level? I'd like to avoid if possible an upper level form/view-based solution.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to specify this at the database level in Django. You could check for this in your model's `clean()` or `validate_unique()` methods, but those methods are only called in certain circumstances.

One approach would be to restructure your database so that you use a single table for students and lecturers, distinguishing them with a `role` column.

```
class ClassGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(_('group'), max_length=3) 
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='classgroups', 
                                       related_query_name='classgroup',
                                       verbose_name=_('course')) 
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='classgroups',
                                           through='ClassRole')


    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = _('class group') 
        verbose_name_plural = _('class groups') 
        unique_together = ('group', 'course')

class ClassRole(models.Model):
    class_group = models.ForeignKey(ClassGroup, related_name='roles')
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, related_name='roles')

    STUDENT_ROLE = 10
    LECTURER_ROLE = 20
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (STUDENT_ROLE, _('student role')),
        (LECTURER_ROLE, _('lecturer role')),
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

In this structure there is of course only role per actor. You can also write custom `Managers` and model methods to make it easy to get at just the students or lecturers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Your solution is undoubtedly very good, but my team and me are in an advanced state of progress with our project, so we'd like to avoid model changes since we'd need to refactor a lot of things.
However we'll check if it is possible to go ahead with your idea. If it isn't, then I think we will define a clean() method (which actually sucks, but we haven't a better idea).